# printing parts of string that contains av in java

Tags: java, split, contains

I´m trying to take Strings of input and print out the words that contain "av"

Here is my code:

```
        while (true) {
        String jono = lukija.nextLine();
        String[] loydaAvSana = jono.split(" ");

        if (jono.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("loppu");
            break;

        }

        if(jono.contains("av")){
            for(int i = 0; i < loydaAvSana.length; i++){
                System.out.println(loydaAvSana[i]);
            }
        }
```

for example, if I write: Hello World 
It shouldn't do anything, but when I write for example

"avaava ovi ava"

it should print:

avaava

ava

So it should get the Strings that contain "av"

I know that I should use split method and also contains method but I don't know how to print only the strings that contain "av"

My codes output is like this:

```
Hello world
ava ovi ava
ava
ovi
ava
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
while (true) {
    String jono = lukija.nextLine();
    if (jono.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("loppu");
        break;
    }

    if(jono.contains("av")){
        String[] loydaAvSana = jono.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < loydaAvSana.length; i++){
            if (loydaAvSana[i].contains("av") {
                System.out.println(loydaAvSana[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Read the next line.
- If it's empty, exit the loop.
- Otherwise, check if it conatins "av".
- If it does, split it into words.
- Iterate through all the words.
- If a word contains "av", print that word.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, you should insert an if statement that sees if the i-th element of the array contains "av," similar to how you checked the overall string.